# Random graph with structures

Tags: c

I am trying to implement code for a random graph, where all vertices are connected to each other. The edges should be randomly selected. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define VOL 100

struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *read_list(void){
    struct node *p, *first=NULL;
    int i,V;

    for(i=0;i<V;i++){
        p=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->next=first;
        p->info=rand()%V;
        first=p;
    }
    return(first);
}

void print_list(struct node *p){
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("%d-> ", p->info);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    return;
}

int read_graph(struct node *G[]){
    int i, V;
    printf("Select a number of vertices:\n");
    scanf("%d", &V);
    for(i=0;i<V;i++){
        printf("Adjacency list of vertex %d:\n", i);
        G[i]=read_list();
    }
    return(V);
}

void print_graph(struct node *G[], int V){
    int i;
    printf("Adjacency lists of the graph:\n");
    for(i=0;i<V;i++){
        printf("Adjacency vertices to %d: ",i);
        print_list(G[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int adj(int i, int j, struct node *G[]){
    int r;
    struct node *p;
    p=G[i];
    while (p!=NULL && p->info !=j)
        p=p->next;
    if(p==NULL)
        r=1;

    else
        r=0;
    return (r);
    }


int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    struct node *G[VOL], *L;
    int V;
    V=read_graph(G);
    print_graph(G, V);
    L=read_list();
    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't work and I don't know why. Xcode tells me 'build succeeded" but the code prints nothing (currently only 'Select a number of vertices'): no adjacency list, no edges.. Could you please check it and tell me where the errors are?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error description. What doesn't work? Does it compile? Does it link? Does it give the wrong output? What did you expect? What are your debug efforts?

Comment: Xcode tells me 'build succeeded" but the code prints nothing (currently only 'Select a number of vertices'): no adjacency list, no edges...

Comment: @math.world. Please edit your question with a precise description of the issue you are experiencing. Do not put relevant information in the comments.

Comment: Perhaps type the number of vertices, press Enter and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` statement below, the variable `V` is not initialized.

```
...
struct node *read_list(void) {
  struct node *p, *first = NULL;
  int i, V;  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< V not initialized

  for (i = 0; i<V; i++) {
              //^ trouble here
...
```